# Powerapps how to append data from form to an existing Excel File

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-collection

I created the Powerapps form below. My goal is to have a user fill out this form, click Save, and have the data appended to an Excel file.

I connected the individual drop down boxes to a SQL database. The drop downs all work correctly and show the data that I want the user to choose from.

I don't understand how to take the data from this form and append the data to an existing Excel spreadsheet. I saw something that said I had to make a Collection out of it and I think that part worked. But the next step said to use the Patch function and I keep getting errors referencing the drop down values in the Patch statement.  It accepts the text fields, just not the drop downs.  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I am winging it with Powerapps and it's hard to find specific information on what I'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help.

```
Collect
( MyItems, 
    {LocIdC: LocationId.SelectedText, CatIdC: CategoryIdSelected.SelectedText, SubCatIdC: SubCategoryId.SelectedText,
    ClientIdC: ClientId.SelectedText, EventIdC: EventId.Text, CharityIdC: CharityId.SelectedText,
    DateSelectedC: DateSelected.SelectedDate, WeightC: WeightTons.Text, UnitsC: Units.Text, DollarsC: Dollars.Text } );
```

ClearCollect(myCSV, {csvString:"LocIdC,CatIdC,SubCatIdC,ClientIdC,EventIdC,CharityIdC,DateSelectedC,WeightC,UnitsC,DollarsC"&Char(10)});

ForAll(
MyItems,
Patch(
myCSV,
First(myCSV),
{csvString: First(myCSV).csvString&LocIdC&","&CatIdC&","&SubCatIdC&","&ClientIdC&","&EventIdC&","&CharityIdC&","&DateSelectedC&","&WeightC&","&UnitsC&","&DollarsC&Char(10)})
);

[image: Current Powerapps form]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .selectedText, try .Selected.Value

Comment: That just gives me an error in the function that says "Name isn't valid.  This identifier isn't recognized.".

Comment: Then your PowerFX command has gotten the wrong reference. You are giving it the wrong input.